# why my group by still give double row ? (in relation 3 table)

Tags: mysql, sum, left-join, inner-join

[image]

```
select t_loan.id_customer, t_loan.id_loan, 
sum(t_loan_item.Quantity * t_loan_item.unit_price) as total_loan,
sum(t_loan_payment.amount_payment) as total_payment
from t_loan
inner join t_loan_item on t_loan.id_loan = t_loan_item.id_loan
left join t_loan_payment on t_loan.id_loan = t_loan_payment.id_loan
group by t_loan.id_loan
```

my goal is to show : 
       1. total_loan each id_loan and id_customer from t_loan_item
       2. total amount payment each id_loan and id_customer from t_loan_payment
my problem is : it's look like query with group by still make 2 row so it's make total_loan and total_payment are double

Comment: IT"S CLOSED ... i got the answer.

Comment: select t_loan.id_customer, t_loan.id_loan, (select sum(t_loan_item.Quantity * t_loan_item.unit_price) from t_loan_item where t_loan.id_loan=t_loan_item.id_loan) as total_loan, 
(select sum(t_loan_payment.amount_payment) from t_loan_payment where t_loan.id_loan = t_loan_payment.id_loan) as total_payment
from t_loan
group by t_loan.id_loan

Comment: please post your solution as an answer, not a comment